# What does it mean when you pass a variable={} into a function?

Tags: javascript

What does something like this achieve?

```
function myFunction(foo, bar={}, boo){
//?
}
```

Comment: This is not valid javascript. Did I miss something?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: Are you running some sort of preprocessor to your Javascript?  That would be the only way to make something like this work.  It would be easy enough to write a preprocessor that interpreted that in the way it's obviously intended.  But I've never seen one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid JS. In other languages this will set the argument to the value `{}` if bar is not specified, but it would only make sense if the default value was the last argument, or the arguments could be named when the function is called.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer his question. It is possible to pass an object to a function!!! Although his code sample isn't working, his question should be answered...

Comment: I assumed he asked what `foo = {}` syntax as a parameter declaration meant since that was the code he wrote. And my answer was accepted...

Answer (score 1):

It achieves `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` i.e. its not valid JavaScript